# java mongo about org.bson.BsonSerializationException

Tags: java, mongodb

Recently I found that Java-mongodb-driver offered some exceptions:

```
org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Detected unknown BSON type "\xce" for fieldname "����\�z". Are you using the latest driver version?
        org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.readBsonType(BsonBinaryReader.java:95)
        com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getField(ProtocolHelper.java:87)
        com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.isCommandOk(ProtocolHelper.java:82)
        com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:113)
        com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
        com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
        com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:176)
        com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:216)
        com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:207)
        com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:113)
        com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:516)
        com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:510)
        com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:431)
        com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:404)
        com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
        com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
        com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
        com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
        com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:216)
        com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:156)
```

I want to know what circumstance can cause this problem, how to solve

Comment: mongo-java-driver 3.4.1 & mongodb 3.2.4

Comment: try this https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/issues/184 and http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/